# Script App to create a COMBO chart out of COLUMN and SCATTER in Google Spread

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets

not sure if I can insert script parts from Google's Chart Service into Google Spread Script but I wanted to visualize a COLUMN and SCATTER COMBINED chart, which is not within the default chart options of Google Spread but would look like this:

[image]

the image was created with two charts on each other where the chart on the top has transparent background color but the only problem with this is that when a) PRINTING THE FILE or b) SAVING AS PDF would both turn the background color to WHITE and the workaround would be killed.

I tried something similar stuffs but none was working. The chart appears as the default COMBO charts.

Does anyone have an idea how to make it possible?
so very precisely: CAN THE OPTION SET in some ways that you could control series independently? --> .setOption('series(2)', {type: 'scatter'})

```
  var chart = riports.newChart()
    .addRange(datarng)
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .asComboChart()
    .setOption('series(2)', {type: 'scatter'})
    .build()

  riports.insertChart(chart)
```

Comment: @WhiteHat looks like you can not let Apps Script to swallow different COMBO charts only the built-ins. the right syntax would be: .setOption(‘series.1.type’, ‘scatter’) or ‘linechart’ but nothing works! as if you havent set any new Option

Comment: @I'-'I Google’s Chart Service to visualize whatever chart I want and than embed it into the spread?